# Why did I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 on my Insertion sort code?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Why do I get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`in my Insertion sort on this line: `while ((a[j].compareTo(a[j - 1]) > 0) && j > 0)`

```
 public static <T extends Comparable> void inserionSort(T[] a) {
            int j, i;
            for (i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
                //initial condition 
                j = i;
                while ((a[j].compareTo(a[j - 1]) > 0) && j > 0) {
                     
                    swap(j, j - 1, a); 
                    j--;
                }
                 
            }
            display(a);
    
        }
```

Is there any problem with my algorithm?

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:` 1 or -1?

Comment: maybe if you evaluate j>0 before a[j].compareTo(a[j - 1]) > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking j > 0 after (a[j].compareTo(a[j - 1]) , hence in case of j == 0 a[0-1] will be evaluated before j > 0.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, `j = 1` and after swapping j becomes 0. And `a[j-1]` is `a[-1]` which gives you that exception.

If you put `j>0` before the condition, it should work